# For each row returned, also return a list of rows that match on some other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

For example:

I have a database of students and last classes, and for each student in a class, I also return a list of all the other students in the class. Sample table would be like

```
StudentID ClassID
a          1
b          1
c          1
a          2
a          3
c          2
b          3
```

I want to select of studentID = a classes, but also know what other students will be in his class as so:

```
StudentID  ClassID  Classmates
a          1        a,b,c
a          2        a,c
a          3        a,b
```

I tried doing a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(StudentID)
FROM enrolled GROUP BY studentID, ClassID)
AS temporary WHERE temporary.StudentID=a
```

The problem is that `GROUP BY` condenses the rows, so returning a list of `b`'s classes wouldnt show anything because `a` is prioritized in the studentID column.

I researched everywhere and couldn't find anything -- help?

Comment: could you also post in question what you get after trying your code?

Comment: Running the query where temporary.StudentID=a returns the table desired, but it returns nothing for temporary.StudentID=b or temporary.StudentID=c because a is prioritized over b and c for each class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
select e.studentid, e.classid, dt.classmates
from (
    select classid, group_concat(studentid) as classmates
    from enrolled
    group by classid
) as dt
join enrolled e on e.classid = dt.classid
where e.studentid = 'a'
```

The basic idea is to generate the classmates lists by grouping on just `classid` and then join that to `enrolled` so that you can select the student you're interested in.

When you use `where e.studentid = 'a'`, you get this:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| studentid | classid | classmates |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| a         |       1 | a,b,c      |
| a         |       2 | a,c        |
| a         |       3 | a,b        |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

filtering on `e.studentid = 'b'` yields:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| studentid | classid | classmates |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| b         |       1 | a,b,c      |
| b         |       3 | a,b        |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

and filtering on `e.studentid = 'c'` gives you this:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| studentid | classid | classmates |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| c         |       1 | a,b,c      |
| c         |       2 | a,c        |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: I found this solution while Googling a similar problem, and it was exactly what I was looking for! Much appreciated! I do have a question though, if you could: Suppose I needed another column that would also contain multiple values, like a 'test scores' column; how would I add another to the query?

Comment: @dlwiest: I'm not sure what your situation is but perhaps join to another derived table.

Comment: @mu I'm building a polling system, where the choices and votes are each stored on their own tables. I used exactly the syntax you suggested, more or less, to join the list of choices associated with a given poll to that poll, but I also need to do the same with the list of votes, and I'm not sure where that fits in.

Comment: @dlwiest: Maybe ask a question (with a possible reference back to here) so that you have more room to describe your situation and what your tables look like.